# Fill drop down list from external json

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to JSON and struggling with the following.

I have an external JSON file

```
teamSkills = '[\
    {"name":"John", "team":"Red"}, \
    {"name":"Anna", "team":"Green"}, \
    {"name":"Peter", "team":"Orange"}\
]
```

I want my HTML file to read the team names and populate a drop down list.  From searching the web and 'playing' with the code, I now have the following JavaScript however it uses an array not the external JSON (which will contain a lot of records):

```
var TeamName = ["Red", "Green", "Orange"];
var sel = document.getElementById('teamList');
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
TeamName.forEach(function(team, index) {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.innerHTML = team;
  opt.value = team;
  fragment.appendChild(opt);
});
sel.appendChild(fragment);
```

The HTML code:

```
<select id="teamList"></select>
```

Can this be updated to get the data from the external JSON file?

Comment: That's not really JSON if there is variable assignment. Why do you have your JavaScript Array as a String?

Comment: I'm new to JSON I thought that is how it was done... oops  The JavaScript Array is how I copied from the net, I am very new to all this (as it shows! lol)

Comment: [JSON](https://www.json.org/) is just the Object Notation. JavaScript Objects are similar, but they can have functions as properties, and be assigned to `var`s. If you just have a page of JavaScript, then your Objects or Arrays should not be Strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array of objects and an array of strings are almost the same thing. You can  replace `TeamName` with `teamSkills` then access the `team` from the inner object:

```
// Not sure what is the initial format of your data here,
// use JSON.parse('your string') if you have a string to start with
var teamSkills = [
    {"name":"John", "team":"Red"},
    {"name":"Anna", "team":"Green"},
    {"name":"Peter", "team":"Orange"}
];
var sel = document.getElementById('teamList');
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
// Here, iterate through the skills instead
teamSkills.forEach(function(skill, index) {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  // Here, access the team from the current skill object
  opt.innerHTML = skill.team;
  opt.value = skill.team;
  fragment.appendChild(opt);
});
sel.appendChild(fragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can use this code it will be working good with you

```
$.each(TeamName, function(key, value) {   
$('#teamList').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",key).text(value)); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for using different code :

```js
let dropdown = $('#teamList');

const teamSkills = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1abhwz';

// Populate dropdown with list of provinces
$.getJSON(teamSkills, function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, entry) {
    dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.name).text(entry.team));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="teamList"></select>
```